# SSRS Correcting #Error

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS expression where sometimes the denominator is 0, and I get a #DIV error so I added a +.0001 to eliminate the #DIV error, but when I add a FLOOR syntax I get an #ERROR, and I can't figure out to remove the #ERROR.  The result should be NULL is I add the FLOOR syntax.

Code 1 without FLOOR:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Handled.Value) > 0, Sum(Fields!talktime.Value) / Sum(Fields!Handled.Value+.0001), "")
```

Code 2 with FLOOR:

```
=FLOOR(IIF(Sum(Fields!Handled.Value) > 0, Sum(Fields!talktime.Value) / Sum(Fields!Handled.Value+.0001), ""))
```

Comment: Maybe **NOTHING** would work better? I think the error is from `FLOOR("")`.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the divide by zero error you would need to add the following custom code to your report:

Function CalculateFraction(ByVal Numerator As Double, ByVal Denominator As Double) As Double

If Denominator = 0 Then
          CalculateFraction = 0
Else
          CalculateFraction = Numerator / Denominator
End If
Return CalculateFraction
End Function

And then insert the following expression into the desired textbox and format according:

=Code.CalculateFraction(Fields!Numerator.Value, Fields!Denominator.Value)

Comment: figured it out. IIF(Sum(Field)>0,Floor(Sum(Field) / iif(Sum(Field)>0,sum(Field),-1)), "")